# mobile multilevel navigation pattern

Tags: mobile, navigation

Hi I currently conceive a mobile website and the navigation.
I have a problem with certain pages.
in the one hand these pages have 5-7 undersites and on the other hand hand these pages have content.
with a navigation like the nike.com mobile site, it is possible to navigate to a underpage. but these navigation pattern is not good for pages, which have underpages and own content.

do you know a good navigation pattern, to solve my problem?
i created a mockup. but i think it is not the best way to solve my problem.

[image: http://s14.directupload.net/images/130801/5faim2fs.jpg]
<sup>Click for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Why not just autoscroll away the super pages, so only the navbar, current page title, and its subpages it shown. If you scroll up, you'll see the whole path and be able to click-to-back, but if you scroll down, the page title will be fixed under the navbar, with a small font size, and the subpages will scroll up away and be hidden.